# How direct mapped, set associative and fully associative caching works in mips?

Tags: caching, mips

i have troubles trying to understand how direct mapped, set associative and fully associative caching techniques works.
i have 3 caches (one for each technique) made by 8 blocks of 4 bytes, and i'm trying to insert those values : 0, 16, 0, 24, 32 and understand which one will hit or miss.

i tried to made a direct mapped structure using 2 LSB as offset, 3 as index and 1 as tag, getting miss, miss, hit, miss, miss but actually i can't tell if it is right.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RX9 i tried to made a direct mapped structure using 2 LSB as offset, 3 as index and 1 as tag, getting miss, miss, hit, miss, miss but actually i can't tell if it is right..

Comment: You should add it to your post. Chances are you will get more help that way.